# javascript works on checkout not in check in

Tags: javascript, check-out, check-in

I am using SP2013 & giving a JavaScript on homepage but the problem is it works when the homepage is checkout as soon as I check in the script doesn't work. what might be the reason ???

Comment: Use the Content Editor Webpart or the Script Editior webpart to add the javascript snippet to the page.

Comment: can you share your code here.so that we can check .

Comment: How do you embed the JS code in homepage? Also please try use F12 tool to check whether your JS code is working after checked in.

Comment: Show us the code how you add JS to you homepage